# Let $E$ be the splitting field of $x^4+x+1$ over $\mathbb Z_2$. Find $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb Z_2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

> Let $E$ be the splitting field of $x^4+x+1$ over $\mathbb Z_2$. Find $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb Z_2)$.

I found that $$E=\{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d+\langle x^4+x+1\rangle\mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z_2\}.$$

Let $\alpha=x+\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$.
Then I know that $E= \mathbb Z_2(\alpha)$ and $E$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{GF}(2^4)$.

How can I get  $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb Z_2)$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about the Frobenius endomorphism, or about the group of units of a finite field? It is easy to do this concretely, albeit a bit painful--if you had general machinery the computation would be much easier.

Comment: You know the degree of $E$ over ${\bf Z}_2$, so you know the number of elements in the Galois group, right? And there aren't that many groups with that number of elements. So you just have to look for automorphisms to distinguish among those groups.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok I got what you saying! thanks

Comment: Good! So, can you solve the problem, and post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

A $\Bbb F_2[x]$ polynomial is even in its number of monomial terms iff it vanishes at $\mathbf 0:=0+\frac{\Bbb Z}{2\Bbb Z}$ or $\mathbf 1:=1+\frac{\Bbb Z}{\Bbb Z}$. Consequently, $x^2+x+\mathbf 1$ is the only $\Bbb F_2[x]$ quadratic irreducible and thus $f(x):=x^4+x+\mathbf 1$ is irreducible or else, because $f(x)$ has no $\Bbb F_2$ roots, we'd have the absurdity $$x^4+x+\mathbf 1=f(x)=(x^2+x+\mathbf 1)^2=x^4+x^2+\mathbf 1$$  Fix a field isomorphism $\varphi:\frac{\Bbb F_2[x]}{\langle f(x)\rangle}\to\Bbb F_{2^4}$ and let $\alpha=\varphi(x+\langle f(x)\rangle)$. Now, $\{\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^4,\alpha^8\}$ is both the set of four $f(x)$ roots and the  permutation orbit of $\alpha$ under the frobenius $\Bbb F_{2^4}$ field automorphism $\varphi:t\mapsto t^2$. $$\therefore\;4\leq\text{ord}(\varphi)\leq|\text{Gal}(\Bbb F_{2^4}/\Bbb F_2)|=4\;\;\;\;\;\therefore\;\text{Gal}(\Bbb F_{2^4}/\Bbb F_2)=\langle\varphi\rangle\approx\Bbb Z_4^+$$